# Parse Push Ceriticate Certificate is invalid. Double check that you didn't export it with a password

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have created development cerification for push and generated p12 file. But when i upload that it is saying . "Certificate is invalid. Double check that you didn't export it with a password."

!(http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=3d60138) [looks like this.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit late but maybe it will help someone else. For exporting the certificate without password, leave the following fields empty while exporting.
[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I'm doing. But still get the error :(